# Calculating derivative of quantities in a 2D and 3D meshes

Tags: c, simulation, computational-geometry, game-physics, mesh

I am new to physics of games. I have a problem where i have a 2D or 3D mesh. The computational cells are triangles or tetrahedrons respectively. Certain physical quantities like density and energy are given at cell centers as cell centered averages. I need to compute the gradient of these quantities at the center of all the cells in the mesh.

I understand that in 1D, the derivative of a quantity in a cell (i) can be calculated by dividing the difference of values of that quantity in the neighboring cells (i+1,i-1) by the distance between them (central difference formula). What i don't understand is to solve this problem on an arbitrary 2D or 3D mesh?

Can i get reference to some literature where i can get such numerical methods/algorithms ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[This paper](http://www.multires.caltech.edu/pubs/diffGeoOps.pdf) is a good place to start when thinking about differential operators on a mesh.  It doesn't get into volumetric meshes (if I recall), but it's a good start.  In particular, the paper presents a sound choice for assigning gradients at the vertices from a discrete differential geometry point of view (DDG), from which you can use barycentric coordinates to compute a gradient field on the interior of the facets.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of a multi-variate function is a vector.  For simplicity let's assume we are dealing with a 2d mesh, then the derivative is a 2d vector.  To simplify things further, let's take the derivative at position **(x,y)=(0,0)** .  To get started, you have to identify all adjacent cells, with their centers **(x1,y1), (x2,y2)...** and values **z1, z2, ...** .  Optionally, you can assign a (non-negative) weight to each of them, depending on the distance, like e.g. **wk=(d*d - xk*xk - yk*yk)** with **d** the maximum distance of adjacent cells to consider here. Then you approximate all those adjacent values using linear regression: **z = vx*x+vy*y + z0**.  The values of **vx, vy, z0** are obtained by least square regression:

minimize **Sum_k[wk * (zk - vx*xk - vy*yk - z0)^2]**

where the index k iterates over all neighbors.  The vector **(vx,vy)** is the derivative you are looking for.

Comment: Intresting. If i were to quantify the accuracy of these derivatives, would i be wrong to call the derivatives "second order accurate"?

Comment: Is this "Weighted least squares estimation"? Why not the "weight" is square root of this wk？

Answer (score 0):

well the derivative of a polygon in a mesh is the plane of the polygon, if you need to be more granular than that then it can be done several different ways, you can estimate it by averaging and weighting the adjacent polygons.

Comment: I don't mean derivative of a polygon, i mean to calculate the derivative of quantities such as density and energy, for which values are already defined at the cell centers.

Comment: maybe you should change your search parameters to look for interpolation...and you can make it as simple or complex as appropriate. like if you had point a, at which you wanted to estimate some Property P, you can try just doing a very naive algorithm that adds the property of adjacent node l,m,n... times a scaling factor that represents an inverse of the total distance of all sampled nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Nor will you ever understand how to calculate such a derivative, because technically, it isn't possible. You can only ever interpolate a true discrete derivative over cells back to cells, but it isn't defined there.

Now that does not sound very helpful, I know, and I cannot really explain all that very well in the space given here. But if you want to do yourself a favor, read up on discrete exterior calculus. It may sound like a bit of scary terminology at first, but it will make your life a lot easier, quite fast.

Try google, or start following references here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.3076